# Clear a log file that is still accessed by its program

Tags: batch-file, logging

I regularly clear a log file as I run some tests and I want to keep that log readable.

I have a batch file using the command below that works whenever the program that is being logged is turned off.

`del /f *.log`

When the program (a tomcat server) is running, I have an 'access is denied' error because the file is being used by another service.

I don't want to turn the tomcat off and on every time. My current workaround is to edit the log into notepad++, select all, delete, save and close notepad++.

Is there a more efficient way of doing that? I have a few batch to clean multiple times a day so I would like to automate.

Is it possible to create a .bat that would do that for me? I thought of exporting a notepad++ macro into a batch file but my various research were not successful.

I tried:

`echo off
 echo. > filename.log`

but the result is the same => access is denied because the file is already in use.

Comment: If the program has a file lock on the log file I do not think there is much you can do on that end. However what is writing the log file? I would guess you can maybe adjust the log level and or have it create another log file once it  gets to the desired length. That way you can delete the old files.

Comment: Please, test if `echo Any text >> filename.log` correctly _appends_ the text in the file. If so, I may have a solution to your problem via a 3rd party program...

Comment: @ Randy : Unfortunately, adjusting log level or setting a ma length doesnt work as my logs are created by a program I'm testing in the frame of my work and testing procedures are as different as the tests I run everyday.

@Aacini: I've tried echo.> "filename.log" resulting in a second file created whose name was " "filename.log" " (quotes inside the quotes are part of the file name :-p ). However, as its a corporate computer, I'd rather not install any third party programs. 

What about exploiting notepad++ as it is already able to edit and save the file during its usage... any ideas on that?

Comment: So far, the closest solution I have found to do this is to create a macro in notepad++ that does: `Select all, delete, save then closes the file`.

I was just wondering if that macro could be triggered by a batch file?